# there is no telegram tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tags

I was going to ask some question about telegram app and I noticed that there is no telegram related tag!
Please add "telegram" and telegram related (such as telegram-desktop and such) tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added [telegram-messenger](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/telegram-messenger) to your question.

In the future, it may be best to add a note at the bottom of your question stating that you'd like to have a particular tag created for it. We'll consider whether it's appropriate to add the tag to the question, then edit out the note once we've decided.

There is no need to have additional tags for the different versions of the Telegram app; such tags would be too narrowly scoped, and mobile devices (except where they interface with a computer) are considered off-topic for Super User so they would not be useful anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't a better tag be "telegram-messenger"? Just "telegram" feels a bit vague and potentially open to misuse.

Comment: @Mokubai: Addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the question. I'm sure there is SOMETHING you could tag it with for now.

Users that have the rep will eventually stumble by, and may feel like adding the tag, if it's a good add.